# Confused by how to link Gnosis SAFE to our treasury wallet to utilize multi-sig

Tags: gnosis-safe

I apologize up front if this is an elementary question. Here is the situation: A group of us with the concurrence of the lead developer have agreed to migrate an existing crypto project that is already functioning and trades on a dex to multi-sig authorization and with the eventual goal of migrating to a DAO. Our first goal is to secure the integrity of the treasury wallet which is where the tax on buys/sells of the token are paid to by smart contract. From this wallet are paid all the projects expenses, etc. Our intent is to use a newly created SAFE wallet to set up the multi sig authorization. I fully understand how to add signatory wallets to the SAFE wallet but what I am completely not understanding is how the SAFE wallet becomes linked to the Treasury Wallet I referenced just above? I do not understand where and what information I need to provide in the SAFE interface to make sure that the Treasury Wallet is secured by multi sig.

Edit and update: Perhaps my brain just functioned and I realized that the SAFE wallet actually will become the new TREASURY WALLET for our project and we have to change the code in the smart contract so that it sends all tax payments to the new SAFE WALLET address. Is this correct?

Thanks, John